# Where do log files and configuration files belong on Windows server?

Tags: windows, configuration, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a .Net Windows Service (WCF). What is the preferred location for configuration and log files? The assemblies get installed into C:\Program Files\CompanyName\ProductName and currently that's where log files and configuration files go, although I have a feeling that it's not the right place for them.

We're targeting Server 2012 R2 right now, but using WIX to create an installer. I see some other similar questions, but they are dated 2008 and they don't point to any MS guidelines.